# Capturing a text submitted in a Search Bar in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a search bar (Text filter custom visual) and I need to capture the value submitted.

Is there a way to do it?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do overall? If you could capture (you can't) the value entered, what will you do with it?